# How do I access the text within an asp.net mvc textbox via javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I access the text within an asp.net mvc textbox via JavaScript?

Basically, I have 2 textboxes which you can see below and I am using the javascript below to access the text selected via the date-picker and outputted to the textboxes but what I have done so far, seems to return null values.

Code:

```
@Html.Label("Start", "Start Date:")
@Html.TextBox("Start", string.Empty, new {@id = "Start", @class = "datepicker"})
@Html.Label("endd", "End Date:")
@Html.TextBox("endd", string.Empty, new {@id = "End", @class = "datepicker"})
<input type="submit" value="Apply" id ="DateSelected" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
$("#DateSelected").onclick(function () {
            var value1 = document.getElementById('<%=Start.ClientID%>').value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById('<%=End.ClientID%>').value;

</script>
```

Comment: Since you already defined the html id like `@id = "Start"`, you can just do `document.getElementById('Start')`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? The value of the textboxes are the selected dates so why do you need to get the value and then set it again to the same value?

Comment: If you have a better method of grading a txt equivalent of these selected dates go ahead

Comment: If you using a date picker, it kind of assumes you want a date so why aren't your properties `public DateTime Start` and `public DateTime endd`? but in any case when you post back, the values posted back are strings (but if your properties are `DateTime` the `DefaultModelBinder` will convert them for you)

Comment: This seems to be related to [JS grabbing text from text-boxes, passing to asp.net mvc ActionResult but ActionResult parameters appear null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529838/js-grabbing-text-from-text-boxes-passing-to-asp-net-mvc-actionresult-but-action) so you can get the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your Javascript to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    $("#DateSelected").onclick(function () {
            var value1 = document.getElementById('Start').value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById('End').value;

</script>
```