# JS grabbing text from text-boxes, passing to asp.net mvc ActionResult but ActionResult parameters appear null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

JS grabbing text from text-boxes, passing to asp.net mvc ActionResult but ActionResult parameters appear null

I have 2 textboxes which are filled by 2 datepickers upon the user's selection but although the information grabs correctly from the textboxes when I use the below javascript to pass it to the actionresult. The parameters of the actionresult show to be null.

How do I fix?

Code:

```
@Html.Label("Start", "Start Date:")
@Html.TextBox("Start", string.Empty, new {@id = "Start", @class = "datepicker"})
@Html.Label("endd", "End Date:")
@Html.TextBox("endd", string.Empty, new {@id = "End", @class = "datepicker"})
<input type="submit" value="Apply" id ="DateSelected" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
$("#DateSelected").click(function () {
        var startD = $('#Start').val().toString();
        var endD = $('#End').val().toString();
                $.ajax({
                url: '/Docs/FirstDoc',
                type: "Post",
                data: { start: String.valueOf(startD), end: String.valueOf(endD) },
            });
</script>
```

Action Result:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FirstDoc(string start, string end)
    {
        FirstDocModel firstDocModel = FirstDocHelper.RunFunction(start, end);
        return PartialView(firstDocModel);
    }
```

Comment: The values of input elements will always be strings. There's no need to convert them.

Comment: I guessed as much, but had no idea what the issue was, so thought it couldn't hurt

Comment: maybe try "contentType: "application/json" in  your ajax call?

Comment: They still appear null with your suggestion

Comment: OK, I just looked at my own code and I think maybe your controller should expect not two strings, but an object with two string properties start and end.

Comment: Just attempted to pass through a string array and the same issue occured

Comment: Not an array, an object with the two properties.

Comment: Could you please explain that through a coded example and I'll try

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was saying - but first of all I too personally find the ajax to MVC controller binding painful sometimes.  It's flexible, but if anything at all is out of place, you just get nulls - as you know.  Anyway...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FirstDoc(MyObject inputObj)
    {
       //use inputObj here as needed
    }
```

Then, you need a definition for the MyObject - to keep it simple

```
public class MyObject{
    string start {get;set;}
    string end {get;set;}
}
```

If all your ducks are in a row, including your options on the ajax side of course, your object 'should' bind.

Comment: How do I use this to perform the functions described above

Comment: instead of " FirstDocModel firstDocModel = FirstDocHelper.RunFunction(start, end);" it would be something like: FirstDocModel firstDocModel = FirstDocHelper.RunFunction(inputObj.start, inputObj.end);  is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, what I mean was within the JavaScript/JQuery how do I set values etc. Thanks (really hoping this works)

Comment: I do it a little different way because the JS data comes from knockout stuff...BUT, I think the way you do this should work with  contentType: "application/json", dataType: "json" in your ajax options - hopefully...

Answer (score 0):

The way you are passing the `data` would work for `type: 'get'` but not for `post`. Try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ start: startD, end: endD }),
```

Comment: Just attempted that and the same issue occured